# First OOP in C++ - Car example

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented

A code challenge between some friends, as I came from a Procedural way of coding, instead of using Objects. The paramaters are below:

> - store the properties of a car
>
>   - colour
>   - make
>   - model
>   - speed
>   - direction
> - demonstrate how these properties are accessed
> - manipulate these properties through standard calls (functions/methods)
>
>   - from rest, accelerate to 60km/h
>   - make a 90-degree left-hand turn
>   - make a 90-degree right-hand turn
>   - accelerate to 90km/h
>   - brake to 0km/h

I am not used to C++, but decided to try it with some tutorials. I do not think I'm doing it correctly though, looking at other examples. Am I demonstrating how the properties are accessed *properly*? Am I using the getters and setters correctly?

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "car.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    car MyCar;
    int randomCrapIDontCareAbout;
    cout << "OOP Code Challenge - Cars" << endl;

    MyCar.SetColour(4); // 1-4 only
    MyCar.SetMake(3); // 1-4 only
    MyCar.SetDirection(2); // 1-4 only
    MyCar.SetModel(1); // 1-4 only
    MyCar.SetSpeed(0); // 1-200 only

    cout << "Initial Values:" << endl;
    MyCar.PrintCurrentCar();

    cout << "Step 1 - From rest, accelerate to 60km/h"<<endl;
    MyCar.SetSpeed(60);
    MyCar.PrintCurrentCar();

    cout << "Step 2 - Make a 90-degree left-hand turn" << endl;
    MyCar.ChangeDirection(-1);
    MyCar.PrintCurrentCar();

    cout << "Step 3 - Make a 90-degree right-hand turn" << endl;
    MyCar.ChangeDirection(+1);
    MyCar.PrintCurrentCar();

    cout << "Step 4 - Accelerate to 90km/h" << endl;
    MyCar.SetSpeed(90);
    MyCar.PrintCurrentCar();

    cout << "Step 5 - Brake to 0km/h" << endl;
    MyCar.SetSpeed(0);
    MyCar.PrintCurrentCar();

    cin >> randomCrapIDontCareAbout;
    return 0;
}
```

## car.cpp

```
#include "car.h"

car::car()
{
    //ctor
    SetColour(1);
    SetDirection(1);
    SetMake(1);
    SetModel(1);
}

car::~car()
{
    //dtor
}
```

## car.h

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class car
{
    public:
        car();
        virtual ~car();
        void PrintCurrentCar() {
            cout << "COLOUR:     ";
            GetColour();
            cout << endl << "MAKE:       ";
            GetMake();
            cout << endl << "DIRECTION:  ";
            GetDirection();
            cout << endl << "MODEL:      ";
            GetModel();
            cout << endl << "SPEED:      ";
            GetSpeed();
            cout << endl << "-----------------------------------------" << endl;
        }
        unsigned int GetColour() {
             switch (m_Colour) {
                case 1:
                    cout << "Red";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "Blue";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "Green";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout << "Yellow";
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Invalid";
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        void SetColour(unsigned int val = 1) {
            if ((val > 4) || (val < 1)) {
                cout << "Error assigning colour. Use numbers 1-4 only";
            } else {
                m_Colour = val;
            }
        }

        unsigned int GetMake() {
            switch (m_Make) {
                case 1:
                    cout << "Ford";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "Honda";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "Toyota";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout << "Pontiac";
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Invalid";
                    return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
        void SetMake(unsigned int val = 1) {
            if ((val > 4) || (val < 1)) {
                cout << "Error assigning Make. Use numbers 1-4 only";
            } else {
                 m_Make = val;
            }
        }
        unsigned int GetModel() {
            switch (m_Model) {
                case 1:
                    cout << "Truck";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "Car";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "Van";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout << "Super Bike";
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Invalid";
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        void SetModel(unsigned int val = 1) {
            if ((val > 4) || (val < 1)) {
                cout << "Error assigning Model. Use numbers 1-4 only";
            } else {
                 m_Model = val;
            }
        }
        unsigned int GetSpeed() {
            cout << m_Speed << "km/h";
            return true;
        }
        void SetSpeed(unsigned int val) {
            if (val > 200) {
                    cout << "Too fast (max speed: 200km/h)";
            } else {
                m_Speed = val;
            }
        }
        unsigned int GetDirection() {
            switch (m_Direction) {
                case 1:
                    cout << "North";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "East";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "South";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout << "West";
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Invalid";
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        void SetDirection(unsigned int val = 1) {
            m_Direction = val;
        }
        void ChangeDirection(int val = 1) {
            int tempDirection = m_Direction + val;
            if (tempDirection > 4) {
                tempDirection -= 4;
            }
            if (tempDirection < 1) {
                tempDirection += 4;
            }
            SetDirection(tempDirection);
        }
    protected:
    private:
        unsigned int m_Colour;
        unsigned int m_Make;
        unsigned int m_Model;
        unsigned int m_Speed;
        unsigned int m_Direction;
};

#endif // CAR_H
```

Comment: Hi, nice to see you on this side of the 'Stack :)

Comment: `GetColour` prints the colour, so call it `PrintColour`. Same for the other methods called GetSomething. (This is not OOP-specific)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are quite a few things you can improve. Here are some:

1. Don't `using namespace` in a header file. That's a bad idea. Refer [to this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for details. Here you are better off qualifying your `cout` calls with `std::`.
2. Your class methods are too lengthy to be declared inline in the header file. You should move most of them, if no all, to the `.cpp`. Usually, only inline small methods like getters and setters that only set/return a variable.
3. `car` is never inherited from, so it should not have a `virtual` destructor. Virtual destructors are associated with inheritance. Until you have an actual need to inherit from `car`, make the destructor non-virtual. Also, since the destructor is a no-op, it could be omitted altogether, when not virtual. Reference: [When should my destructor be virtual, C++ FAQ](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-dtors).
4. I'll second for the suggestion of using [`enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)s for the car properties. `int` convey no meaning, other than the fact that it is a whole number. Enums like `Color`, `Maker` and `Model` would be self-documenting and type safe (e.g. can't assign a `Color` to a `Maker`).
5. Methods that don't mutate member data, such as your `Get*`s should be `const`. This is often referred as [*const correctness*](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness). Example:

   ```
   unsigned int GetColour() const { /* ... */ }
                            ^^^^^
   ```
6. Normally `std::cerr` is used to log execution errors. `std::cout` is for normal program output. That said, you might also consider [**throwing exceptions**](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions) when the inputs in your methods don't match the expected values. However, most of your errors like `"Error assigning Model. Use numbers 1-4 only"` would go away if you used strongly typed enums.
7. As commented by [@immibis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/49331/immibis), having `Get*` methods print/log things is highly unusual. That seems like a violation of the [*single responsibility principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
8. Don't add access level labels to your class if that section is empty. You have a `protected:` section but no protected data or methods. Remove that line.
9. The mix of lower case for types and `PascalCase` for methods is unusual. The usual would be also `PascalCase` for the types, reserving `camelCase` (first letter lowercase) for variables. Though I would personally suggest `PascalCase` for types only and `camelCase` for variables and functions/methods (or anything that can have its memory address taken, being more specific).
10. Lastly, probably the most relevant thing: Initializing and object with `Get/Set` methods is considered bad OOP design. One reason is that if you forget to set up a field, you might end up with a partly constructed object. Other disadvantage is that you can't declare a const instance. The correct way to initialize your `Car` would be using a [parameterized constructor](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors):

    ```
    Car::Car(Colour colour, Direction dir, Maker maker, Model model)
        : m_colour(colour)
        , m_direction(dir)
        , m_maker(maker)
        , m_model(model)
    { }
    ```

    Also worth noting the use of a *constructor initialization list*. That's the proper way of initing member data in a constructor, by calling the constructors of the member objects. It is basically just a comma separated list starting with a `:`.
11. One final note about your usage example: you seem to have this line just to halt the termination of the program until the user types something:

    > ```
    >  int randomCrapIDontCareAbout;
    >  ...
    >  cin >> randomCrapIDontCareAbout;
    > ```

    In that case, it would be more elegant to use [`std::cin.get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/).

Comment: About #3: It is generally preferred to declare all destructors as virtual.  This is for the case that someone else wants to inherit from your class, but is unable to edit it.

Comment: About #9, most times, even the *presence* of setters is bad OO design. Particularly for properties the user shouldn't be able to change after construction. (There's not really a legitimate case for changing the make of a car, for example, without demoting the car object to a simple value holder. If that's all you want, use a struct :P)

Comment: No comment on having GetXYZ methods print things?

Comment: I disagree with the comment about presence of setters being bad: while it looks superfluous it lets you change the implementation, drop in a facade or mock object, and so on. But I agree with the idea of making as much as possible immutable.

Comment: @Carl, I disagree, programmers are generally bad at predicting the future, so [you aren't gonna need it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). And also, most of the time you are not meant to extend a library when you don't have access to source code. See the STL containers; They don't have virtual destructors.

Comment: @immibis, yes indeed it is quite unusual, but... I'll add a note about that. Thanks.

Comment: @pjc50 Immutability aside, setters break the hell out of encapsulation in general. (Providing the ability to set some important internal variable at will is basically the _opposite_ of hiding implementation details, and causes its own problems with how much you can change without breaking compatibility.)  Outside of pure DTOs and the like (which aren't really OO in themselves), they should be used sparingly if at all.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to decide on the naming convention. You use CamelCase for the class methods. In this case the name of the class should be capitalised, like this: `class Car:`. If you don't like the capitalised class names (like in stl) then use the underscore-delimited class methods, like `void print_current_car()`. Honestly I prefer the former. Check [Google coding style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html) as a reference

Now to the coding style. You have a few Set... methods that change the private members to certain values. I would use the enumerators for them. Also, your getter and setter return different types. I would not mix them, or I would use `Print` to the getter to signify that it prints the value:

```
class Car
{
    public:
        enum Colour{
             Red,
             Blue,
             Green,
             Yellow
        };
        Car();
        virtual ~Car();
        void SetColour(Colour clr){m_Colour = clr;}
        Colour GetColour(){return m_Colour;}
        void PrintColour(){
            switch (m_Colour) {
                case Red:
                    cout << "Red";
                    break;
                case Blue:
                    cout << "Blue";
                    break;
                case Green:
                    cout << "Green";
                    break;
                case Yellow:
                    cout << "Yellow";
                    break;
            }
        };

    private:
        Colour m_Colour;
};
```

Also, the `m_` prefix seems very MFC way. I would drop it

And lastly, I would keep only the inline methods in the .h file. I would move all the methods to the cpp file. Why do you have there only the ctor and dtor?